# Docker Build Fails on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

On Linux I used to build docker image like this:

```
docker build -t ubuntu-docker:v1.0.2 ./
```

But on Windows 11 (PowerShell as administrator) I'm getting the following error:

```
PS C:\> docker build -t ubuntu-docker:v1.0.2 ./
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'docker'.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\> docker build -t ubuntu-docker:v1.0.2 ./
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

PS C:\> error checking context: 'can't stat '\\?\C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18''.
```

why is that and how can I fix it? I don't understand the error message

My docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
COPY ./requirements.txt ./web_scraping/
RUN pip3 install -r ./web_scraping/requirements.txt
ADD ./ ./web_scraping/
CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: Try `docker build -t "ubuntu-docker:v1.0.2" ./` - however it probably wrong inside c:\

Answer (score 0):

`./` isn't a valid path on Windows. Use `.` instead (which also works equally well on Linux, so if you switch over to using that, you can use the same build command on Windows and Linux).

Comment: Now I get: `error checking context: 'can't stat '\\?\C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration''.`

Comment: Please show your Dockerfile. It seems a little weird that you've placed it in the root of the C drive. Usually it's placed in a project directory.

Comment: Added my file to the question. Thanks

Comment: Your `ADD` statement tries to copy the entire C drive into the new image, because the build context is the root of the C drive. At some point during the traversal of the C drive, it hits a file that it can't access. In your case, it's C:\Program Files\Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection\Classification\Configuration. You should place your Dockerfile and python program in a directory that only contains those files.